# How to get better labels for this Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

```
PermutationCycles[RandomSample[Range[100], 100]]
creatlistNew[n_] := Block[
    {one2onehundred, sample},
    one2onehundred = Range[n];
    sample = RandomSample[Range[n], n];
    Table[one2onehundred[[i]] -> sample[[i]], {i, n}]
];
rule = creatlistNew[100]
Graph[rule, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

The labels seem to be "on top" of some of the vertices.
How could I improve this automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
radialLabelCoords[rule_, off_ : 3] := 
 Module[{cc = ConnectedComponents[Graph[rule]], 
   vc = Rescale@GraphEmbedding[Graph[Sort@VertexList@rule, rule]]}, 
  Association @ Apply[Join] @
    Map[Module[{rc = Mean[vc[[#]]], vl = #}, 
        Thread[vl -> 
          If[Length@vl == 1, After,
            (vc[[#]] + off Normalize[vc[[#]] - rc] & /@ vl)]]] &] @ cc]
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
rule = creatlistNew[100];

Graph[Sort@VertexList@rule, rule, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v, radialLabelCoords[rule]@v]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Also

```
Graph[rule,   
 PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 VertexSize -> .6, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: **PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", ** is a nicer way to go!

Comment: Unfortunately,  `PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled"` is not documented.

Comment: It is now documented under [Graph > Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Graph[rule, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 100}], 
  VertexSize -> 0.8, VertexShape -> \!\(\*GraphicsBox[CircleBox[{0, 0}],ImageSize->{24., Automatic}]\), ImageSize -> "Large"]]
```

instead of

```
Graph[rule, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

?